# Using Project Config with Delphi 2009 and Finalbuilder 6

Tags: delphi, build-process, delphi-2009, finalbuilder, buildconfig

Does anyone have any experience of using the project config option with the Delphi Compile Action in Finalbuilder 6.

Currently the build server is set up to manually have all the correct search paths, Compiler options etc set directly on the compile action.  This avoids changes to the config file breaking the build, and also search paths etc may be different to dev machines.  However it can be a pain to change as it needs to be done in FB rather than in the project.

With the new BuildConfig options in Delphi2009 (and support for them in Finalbuilder 6) it 
should be possible to keep this config in SCC and make it easier to maintain and update.

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

I use a virtual machine to make a stable build environment, and keep all the options in FinalBuilder. This way I know that I can make a one line change and it will be a good build, with no way I can break things by changes on my dev PC. Of course I do have to update the components etc occasionally, but that can be snapshotted and tested more carefully.

So I guess I've not tried the build config, but I don't want to!